# What is 'x' in def predict_prices(dates, prices, x)

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('/')[1]))
            flt_price = row[3].replace('$', '')
            prices.append(float(flt_price))
    return

def predict_prices(dates, prices, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates, (len(dates), 1))

    svr_lin = SVR(kernel = 'linear', C = 1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel = 'poly', C = 1e3, degree = 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C = 1e3, gamma = 0.1)

    svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)

    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color='green', label='Linear Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Polynomial Model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]


get_data('AAPLHistoricalDataEXAMPLE.csv')

predicted_price = predict_prices(dates, prices, [[14]])
print(predicted_price)
```

I am using the following sample code from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSu00IRRraY&list=PL2-dafEMk2A6QKz1mrk1uIGfHkC1zZ6UU&index=4) video and I'm not sure what the 'x' parameter in the predict_prices function is.

Below, where the function is called, the video uses '29' for x. Can anyone explain what this parameter is?

Answer (score 0):

x is the date of the month when you want to predict the price, so `29` means he is predicting the open price of Apple's stock at `Oct 29`.

As stated at 3:38 in the video, the author said he split the date of the month for the training data input and use the open price for training data output.

In my opinion, this is not a good approach since the date of every month is repeated. This means you will get the same result for Oct 29 and Nov 29 which is not true in the reality.